# do you forget your manners/are you forgetting your manners?

Tags: present-tense

I know that it's correct to say:

> Are you forgetting your manners?

to reprimand someone.

Is it correct to say:

> Do you forget your manners?

To elaborate more on the question.

Upon what circumstances Do you forget your manners? would be fitting?

Comment: No. "***Did** you forget...* or "***Have** you **forgotten**...*" are correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to reprimand someone with the second sentence, then no.

"***Did** you forget...* or "***Have** you **forgotten**...*" are correct.

Comment: "I can imagine 'do you forget your...' _manners, place, etc_ in a Victorian or slightly older setting. It's the sort of thing you find in fan-fic, video games, etc, where the writer wants an 'olden' feel. See in this regard, the equally appalling 'The Outlaws of Ravenhurst' by the American Imelda Wallace (1923) aiming to tell Catholic children about about anti-Catholic persecution in  17th century Scotland which contains: “Benson,” he stormed, “do you forget your place? To whom are you speaking? Those are servant’s duties.”